# Can I install Linux on an old PC that has x86

Tags: linux

This is the first time I've tried to install Linux.  I've been trying to install Debian as that was recommended to me but it says it only supports x64 and x32 architecture.  On checking the old PC I was given to experiment with, I find that it has x86 architecture.  Can I install Linux on this?
If not, how is the architecture determined?  If I take out the CPU and put in another old desktop I have, will it be the same?
Am I wasting my time?

Comment: *There is no such thing as x32 architecture*  There is only x86 and x64.  If you have a 32-bit only processor then you have a x86 processor.

Comment: What is the precise error message? And which CPU (precise!) do you have?

Comment: You are not wasting your time. In this context your x86 architecture should be fully compatible with a 32-bit Debian (x32). But you're not giving us much information to work with. Are you following a guide? How far are you able to get? When are you running into problems and what is the exact error message? What other options have you tried?

Comment: well, I haven't had an error message yet!  I can't get the PC to connect to the internet so I wanted to install Debian on a USB and install it from that.  Flollowing t

Comment: I've been trying to install Debian on a USB drive but following the instructions I looked up the system information to see if it said x32 or x64, which is what it said on the Debian website.  Instead it says x86 so I wasn't sure whether to bother continuing.  The PC won't even boot now and I'm going through the BIOS one more time before work!

Comment: Just like @Ramhound said, there is no such thing as x32. Intel CPUs are either x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit).

Comment: great, thanks for all this advice, I'll crack on with it now I know it's worth the effort.

Answer (score -1):

"x86" architecture refers to the CPU hardware. The term stems from the names of the first INTEL CPUs, called 8086, 80186, 80286 etc. which all run the same machine code. That means for a user, programs for a "x86" architecture run on all CPUs of that family, regardless of the exact CPU name.

PCs (at least since the early '80ties) have an INTEL x86 CPU. Other CPU families are for instance Motorola 68000 (older Macs) or SPARC (Sun workstations), there are quite a few more.

"x32" or "x64" refers to the width (in bits) of a fundamental data structure. Simplyfying a lot, CPUs either use and process 32 bits or 64 bits in one memory access. The main advantage of using 64 bits is that internal counters in an OS now can hold larger numbers and thus can use more memory. x32 OSes on a x86 machine can only use 4 gigabytes of RAM or less.

Why are not all PCs running x64 type Windows or Linux then?
The CPU has to support 64 bit operations. While most of the INTEL CPUs younger than say, 5 years, do, some others don't.
Secondly, in order to work with your hardware you need drivers which interface hardware to the OS. For x64 OS you need 64bit drivers which might not be available.
If you look at your CPU's specification (using a software tool like http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html as the CPU cooler will obstruct the visual inspection) you can find it's details on http://ark.intel.com/.

To just get a notion of how Linux feels like you could just dry-run Linux by booting from a Live CD/DVD before permanently installing it. This way could be quicker than checking on the x64 compatibility of your hardware.

Comment: So if I want to install Linux instead of Windows, why does it matter what my OS uses?  I'm trying to eventually install it on a slave drive and then fit that as the main drive.  I just want to learn how to use linux but maybe I should throw out this ancient PC and figure out a better way.

Comment: It doesn't really matter much. Presumeably, 64bit software runs faster than 32bit software (as data structures of same size are accessed in half the number of accesses) but on older hardware you won't notice much of a difference. x32 linux will install on a wide range of hardware. If unsure, just boot from a Live CD (a bootable linux CD) without installing and test-drive the OS for a while. You will then notice which drivers you will need additionally for your hardware.

Comment: That's what I think I'll do, thanks a lot, appreciate your time